# Why oneOf does not work on my schema in jsonschema?

Tags: jsonschema

My login has different payloads one is:

```
{
   "username": "",
   "pass": ""
}
```

And one of the other is:

```
{
  "username": "",
  "pass": "",
  "facebook": true
}
```

And the last:

```
{
  "username": "",
  "pass": "",
  "google": true
}
```

My schema is as follow:

```
login_schema = {
    "title": "UserLogin",
    "description": "User login with facebook, google or regular login.",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "username": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "pass": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "facebook": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "google": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "oneOf": [
        {
            "required": [
                "username",
                "pass"
            ],
            "additionalProperties": False,
        },
        {
            "required": [
                "username",
                "pass"
                "google"
            ]
        },
        {
            "required": [
                "username",
                "pass",
                "facebook"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "minProperties": 2,
    "additionalProperties": False,
}
```

It should give an error for the below sample:

```
{
  "username": "",
  "pass": "",
  "google": "",
  "facebook": ""
}
```

But it validates the schema successfully! What I have done wrong in the above schema?

EDIT-1:

```
pip3 show jsonschema
Name: jsonschema
Version: 3.0.2
Summary: An implementation of JSON Schema validation for Python
Home-page: https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema
Author: Julian Berman
Author-email: Julian@GrayVines.com
License: UNKNOWN
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: setuptools, six, attrs, pyrsistent
```

EDIT-2:

What I get as an error is:

```
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: {'username': '', 'pass': '', 'google': '12'} is valid under each of {'required': ['username', 'pass', 'google']}, {'required': ['username', 'pass']}
```

A live demo of the error: https://jsonschema.dev/s/mXg5X

Comment: By trying your schema and instance in a live demo (https://jsonschema.dev/s/Z0ZkB) it works as you expect. What library are you using? Can you show the actual code please? The schema itself works just fine.

Comment: You'll actually run into problems with your OTHER instances that you expect to pass validation, which suggests to me that something in your code is making the validation pass every time. example: https://jsonschema.dev/s/7pTlS

Comment: To fix the OTHER issue, the type of `facebook` and `google` should be boolean.

Comment: @Relequestual I do not use it in code I use python console to validate: `validate(data, schema)`

Comment: @Relequestual live demo also gives error when only `username, pass` parameters are given.

Comment: You need to remove the `additionalProperties: false` from `oneOf[0]`. If you want to modify your question a more generic "what am I doing wrong?" I can create an answer for you =]

Comment: @Relequestual I removed `additionalProperties ` from first element of `oneOf`, but I have problem. Could you take a look at the link at the end of the question? Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is really close. You just need to change `/oneOf/0` to

```
{
  "properties": {
    "username": true,
    "pass": true
  },
  "required": ["username", "pass"],
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```

The problem is that `additionalProperties` doesn't consider the `required` keyword when determining what properties are considered "additional". It considers only `properties` and `patternProperties`. When just using `required`, `additionalProperties` considers *all* properties to be "additional" and the only valid value is `{}`.

However, I suggest a different approach. The `dependencies` keyword is useful in these situations.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "username": { "type": "string" },
    "pass": { "type": "string" },
    "facebook": { "type": "boolean" },
    "google": { "type": "boolean" }
  },
  "required": ["username", "pass"],
  "dependencies": {
    "facebook": { "not": { "required": ["google"] } },
    "google": { "not": { "required": ["facebook"] } }
  },
  "additionalProperties": false
}
```